# One XPath expression for different tags

Tags: html, xpath

Is it possible to join tags with 'and' in XPath expression?

example, i need all active elements. They can be selected by two ways that works for me:

1. `.//input[not(@disabled)]`
2. `.//select[not(@disabled)]`

But I need to write one XPath expression for this.
Something like `.//input[not(@disabled)] and .//select[not(@disabled)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.//input[not(@disabled)]|.//select[not(@disabled)]
```

`|` Set operation; returns the union of two sets of nodes

[Boolean, Comparison, and Set Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256081(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.